# What keywords do I use to get a similar patent to US7249263?

Tags: prior-art, search, computers-support, us7249263

Patent [US7249263](http://www.google.com/patents/US7249263) is about authenticating online users using a personality test to create a user behavior profile at registration on a website and then when the user logs in, he authenticates his profile by answering questions provided by the authentication client and based on his answers, his profile and User ID is verified.

What keywords should I use to search for similar patents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **claims** all require the response to a stimulus to be measured by a sensor. One independent claim says the sensor is a polygraph the rest say the sensor picks up EEG signals.  If you are looking for things that related to the claims you might use EEG, stimulus response, compare, match, identify. It is a biometric identification. So biometric authentication EEG might be good. I gave it a try in google patents and it hit on several things with abstracts that look relevant.